# "How to Prove It": using a product of primes plus $1$ to find a new prime

Tags: prime-numbers

In the *Introduction* of the third edition of *How to Prove It*, Velleman presents the modern version of Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes, the one in which you take a number $m = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n + 1$ and note that $m$ is not divisible by any $p_k$. Exercise 3 of the *Introduction* asks

> (a) Use this method to find a prime different from $2, 3, 5,$ and $7$.
>
> (b) Use this method to find a prime different from $2, 5,$ and $11$.

where "this method" refers to the method for

> finding a prime number different from any in a given list of prime numbers

For (a) I just took the product of the primes and added $1$ to arrive at $211$ which indeed is prime. However, the product of the primes in (b) plus $1$ is $111$ which is not prime. I figured that this problem was designed so that the product of all of the primes plus $1$ would be prime, but it wasn't so, so I checked the solution in the appendix to see if I could make sense of what I was supposed to do. The answer to (b) in the appendix is

> The method yields two primes, $3$ and $37$.

Okay, I thought, maybe I'm just supposed to use only some of the primes, after all, $2 + 1 = 3$. But how does the method yield $37$?

Comment: It doesn't. The idea is that the product of the primes, plus $1$, is not guaranteed to be a prime; it's just guaranteed to be either a prime or the product of primes, none of which is in the list. That second possibility is what's represented by part (b). In that case, you will have to factor the number yourself.

Comment: @BrianTung Where does the $37$ come from?

Comment: It comes from $111$. You're presumed to be able to factor a number; it's always a finite, bounded process. (This proof is not intended to yield an algorithm for factoring, in other words.)

Comment: @BrianTung Oh, I see it: $3 \cdot 37 = 111$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon realizing that $2 \cdot 5 \cdot 11 + 1 = 111$ you're supposed to find the prime factors of $111$ which are guaranteed to be different from $2, 5$ and $11$. Those prime factors are $3$ and $37$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).